# Azure ML Workbench Kubernetes Deployment Failed

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to deploy a prediction web service to Azure using ML Workbench process using cluster mode in this tutorial (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/preview/tutorial-classifying-iris-part-3#prepare-to-operationalize-locally)

The model gets sent to the manifest, the scoring script and schema

> Creating
>   service..........................................................Error
>   occurred: {'Error': {'Code': 'KubernetesDeploymentFailed', 'Details':
>   [{'Message': 'Back-off 40s restarting failed container=...pod=...',
>   'Code': 'CrashLoopBackOff'}], 'StatusCode': 400, 'Message':
>   'Kubernetes Deployment failed'}, 'OperationType': 'Service',
>   'State':'Failed', 'Id': '...', 'ResourceLocation':
>   '/api/subscriptions/...', 'CreatedTime':
>   '2017-10-26T20:30:49.77362Z','EndTime': '2017-10-26T20:36:40.186369Z'}

Here is the result of checking the ml service realtime logs

```
C:\Users\userguy\Documents\azure_ml_workbench\projecto>az ml service logs realtime -i projecto
2017-10-26 20:47:16,118 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2017-10-26 20:47:16,120 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
2017-10-26 20:47:17,123 INFO spawned: 'rsyslog' with pid 9
2017-10-26 20:47:17,124 INFO spawned: 'program_exit' with pid 10
2017-10-26 20:47:17,124 INFO spawned: 'nginx' with pid 11
2017-10-26 20:47:17,125 INFO spawned: 'gunicorn' with pid 12
2017-10-26 20:47:18,160 INFO success: rsyslog entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2017-10-26 20:47:18,160 INFO success: program_exit entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2017-10-26 20:47:22,164 INFO success: nginx entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 5 seconds (startsecs)
2017-10-26T20:47:22.519159Z, INFO, 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, , Starting gunicorn 19.6.0
2017-10-26T20:47:22.520097Z, INFO, 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, , Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:9090 (12)
2017-10-26T20:47:22.520375Z, INFO, 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, , Using worker: sync
2017-10-26T20:47:22.521757Z, INFO, 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, , worker timeout is set to 300
2017-10-26T20:47:22.522646Z, INFO, 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, , Booting worker with pid: 22
2017-10-26 20:47:27,669 WARN received SIGTERM indicating exit request
2017-10-26 20:47:27,669 INFO waiting for nginx, gunicorn, rsyslog, program_exit to die
2017-10-26T20:47:27.669556Z, INFO, 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, , Handling signal: term
2017-10-26 20:47:30,673 INFO waiting for nginx, gunicorn, rsyslog, program_exit to die
2017-10-26 20:47:33,675 INFO waiting for nginx, gunicorn, rsyslog, program_exit to die
Initializing logger
2017-10-26T20:47:36.564469Z, INFO, 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, , Starting up app insights client
2017-10-26T20:47:36.564991Z, INFO, 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, , Starting up request id generator
2017-10-26T20:47:36.565316Z, INFO, 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, , Starting up app insight hooks
2017-10-26T20:47:36.565642Z, INFO, 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, , Invoking user's init function
2017-10-26 20:47:36.715933: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instruc
tions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-10-26 20:47:36,716 INFO waiting for nginx, gunicorn, rsyslog, program_exit to die
2017-10-26 20:47:36.716376: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instruc
tions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-10-26 20:47:36.716542: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructio
ns, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-10-26 20:47:36.716703: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructi
ons, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-10-26 20:47:36.716860: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructio
ns, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
this is the init
2017-10-26T20:47:37.551940Z, INFO, 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, , Users's init has completed successfully
Using TensorFlow backend.
2017-10-26T20:47:37.553751Z, INFO, 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, , Worker exiting (pid: 22)
2017-10-26T20:47:37.885303Z, INFO, 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, , Shutting down: Master
2017-10-26 20:47:37,885 WARN killing 'gunicorn' (12) with SIGKILL
2017-10-26 20:47:37,886 INFO stopped: gunicorn (terminated by SIGKILL)
2017-10-26 20:47:37,889 INFO stopped: nginx (exit status 0)
2017-10-26 20:47:37,890 INFO stopped: program_exit (terminated by SIGTERM)
2017-10-26 20:47:37,891 INFO stopped: rsyslog (exit status 0)

Received 41 lines of log
```

My best guess is theres something silent happening to cause "WARN received SIGTERM indicating exit request". The rest of the scoring.py script seems to kick off - see tensorflow get initiated and the "this is the init" print statement.

http://127.0.0.1:63437 is accessible from my local machine, but the ui endpoint is blank.

Any ideas on how to get this up and running in an Azure cluster? I'm not very familiar with how Kubernetes works, so any basic debugging guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi,
you should be able to see the Kubernetes dashboard by navigating to: 127.0.0.1:63437/ui - is this one blank?

Comment: It redirects to http://127.0.0.1:63437/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kubernetes-dashboard/proxy and that is blank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We discovered a bug in our system that could have caused this. The fix was deployed last night. Can you please try again and let us know if you still encounter this issue?